# pyinstaller executable takes more than 8 minutes print out?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have code which runs immediately when I run using python. The code has tkinter module and bunch of if statements. I created a standalone executable and it takes about 8 minutes to give the output for the GUI. I was wondering why it takes so much time to run ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check buffering of `stdout`. You can do `sys.stdout.flush()` to flush out the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a bunch of work before calling `mainloop`, you won't see anything appear until you call `mainloop` or `update`. The only way a window will appear is in response to an event that asks for the window to be displayed, and tkinter can't process events if `mainloop` isn't running.